# React/Express: Inserting an if-statement inside a response promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, post, promise

I'm receiving a a promise response from a POST call to an express backend. I'd like to insert an if statement in the promise and that seems to be breaking it.

This works:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
})
    .then(response =>
        response.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
```

This if else statement breaks the code:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
    })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                response.json()
            } else {
                throw new Error('Something went wrong ...');
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
```

Is such a thing possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an arrow function only has a single statement and no `{}`around its body this will implicitly be treated as the return value. So in your first example `response => response.json()` will implicitly return the result of `response.json()`.

However if you add the `{}` brackets it will not be an implicit return anymore. It does not even matter if it contains an `if` block in that case. You need to explicitly return the result of `response.json()` when defining a body wrapped into `{}`:

```
response => {
    // explicit return needed
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
    }
}
```

[From the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body):

> Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block
>   body".
>
> In a concise body, only an expression is specified, which becomes the
>   explicit return value. In a block body, you must use an explicit
>   `return` statement.

```
var func = x => x * x;                  
// concise body syntax, implied "return"

var func = (x, y) => { return x + y; }; 
// with block body, explicit "return" needed
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning `response.json` in your `if` block. So, in the next `then` method you have no `response` defined. Try this:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
    })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json()
            } else {
                throw new Error('Something went wrong ...');
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
})
```